# how to bind ArrayList to JList

Tags: java, swing, jlist

i have a JList and an ArrayList.How to bind the datas in arraylist to the jlist.Are the any alternative methods?

```
    ArrayList arl = new ArrayList();
    arl.add("1asdsd");
    arl.add("2asdsd");
    arl.add("3asdsd");  
    Object obj = arl.clone();
    JList list = new JList(obj);
```

how to bind the above code.Now the code give an error.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java ArrayLists into JList](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3269516/java-arraylists-into-jlist)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You don't need to clone the ArrayList. Just call toArray()

```
JList list = new JList(arl.toArray());
```

Comment: What is the use of clone() not here.in all aspects?

Answer (score 6):

```
ArrayList<String> aList = new ArrayList<String>();
aList.add("blabla");
aList.add("blublu");
aList.add("blibli");
aList.add("bleble");
DefaultListModel<String> model = new DefaultListModel<String>();
for(String s:aList){
    model.addElement(s);
}
JList<String> contactList = new JList<String>(model);
```

Advantage of this is that you can later add/remove elements to already instantiated JList by adding elements to model using methods addElement(Obj o) and removeElement(Obj o).

Answer (score 3):

```
JList jList = new JList(arrayList.toArray());
```

Answer (score 1):

```
JList list = new JList(arl.toArray());
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is:

```
DefaultListModel Jlista = new DefaultListModel();

public Form1() {

 jList1.setModel(Jlista);

}

public void yourFunction(){
 Jlista.addElement("newElement");
}
```