# JList and ArrayList update

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, jlist

I would like to have example on how to update a JList when I add or remove elements from a ArrayList.

The ArrayList is part of Model class.  The Model class is passed to the view (which is a JPanel containing several swing components, and the JList I want to update) via its constructor.  The model class is also injected in a class that reads values received from the server.  When i received data from the server I add some of them to my arrayList by doing model.getArrayList().add(data).  When I add data to the arrayList i would like to update the JList in my view.  I would like to have help on how to link my ArrayList with my JList.

Comment: isn't this, for example? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6420623/how-to-bind-arraylist-to-jlist

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you create your own `ListModel` you should extend [`AbstractListModel`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractListModel.html) and when implementing your `addElement` method, you need to call a **fire**-method (for notifying the user interface for the update), like:

```
public void addElement(MyObject obj) {
    myArrayList.add(obj);
    fireIntervalAdded(this, myArrayList.size()-1, myArrayList.size()-1);
}
```

You custom ListModel should look something like this:

```
public class MyListModel extends AbstractListModel {

    private final ArrayList<MyObject> myArrayList = new ArrayList<MyObject>();

    public void addElement(MyObject obj) {
        myArrayList.add(obj);
        fireIntervalAdded(this, myArrayList.size()-1, myArrayList.size()-1);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getElementAt(int index) { return myArrayList.get(index); }

    @Override
    public int getSize() { return myArrayList.size(); }
}
```

Comment: Hello, so in the case i need to create the ListModel in my Model class, then i don't need a ArrayList.  I could use the ListModel instead no ?

Comment: @wotan: Your `Model` class should extend `AbstractListModel` and you need an `ArrayList` to have your elements in. It's more work if you want to use `ListModel` then you need to write the notifying by hand.

Answer (score 6):

You need to use a ListModel to control adding and removing items from a JList.   The tutorial is very useful: 
http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html

Here is some example code from the tutorial:

```
listModel = new DefaultListModel();
listModel.addElement("Jane Doe");

listModel.insertElementAt(employeeName.getText(), index);    

int index = list.getSelectedIndex();
listModel.remove(index);
```

If you have an arraylist you could build your own [List Model](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/ListModel.html) around it.

Comment: How can i notify the list model each time i add element to the arraylist ?

Comment: Build your own List Model with the ArrayList as the backing.