# ArrayList.toArray() not converting to the correct type?

Tags: java, arraylist

So, what I got is:

```
class BlahBlah
{
    public BlahBlah()
    {
        things = new ArrayList<Thing>();
    }

    public Thing[] getThings()
    {
        return (Thing[]) things.toArray();
    }

    private ArrayList<Thing> things;
}
```

In the other class I got:

```
for (Thing thing : someInstanceOfBlahBlah.getThings())
{
    // some irrelevant code
}
```

And the error is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [LsomePackage.Thing;
at somePackage.Blahblah.getThings(Blahblah.java:10)
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: I don't think you can.  Or rather, I don't think you can cast the Array object, since it is an `Object[]`.  But I believe you could cast each individual array -element-.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try:

```
public Thing[] getThings()
{
    return things.toArray(new Thing[things.size()]);
}
```

The reason your original version doesn't work is that [`toArray()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#toArray%28%29) returns `Object[]` and not `Thing[]`. You need to use the other form of `toArray` -- [`toArray(T[])`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#toArray%28T%5B%5D%29) -- to get an array of `Things`.

Comment: `.size()` rather than `.length`. Otherwise +1

Comment: The argument doesnt need to have the "right" size, it's only needed for type information iirc. So you can use `new Thing[0]` as argument, or maybe better, use Peter Lawrey's approach with a static final constant.

Comment: @MartinStettner It's better to use `things.toArray(new Thing[things.size()]);`, see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/174093/toarraynew-myclass0-or-toarraynew-myclassmylist-size

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
private static final Thing[] NO_THING = {};
```

and

```
return (Thing[]) things.toArray(NO_THING);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are [2 toArray() functions](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#method_summary).

```
    Object[] toArray()
        Returns an array containing all of the elements in this list in the correct order.
    <T> T[] toArray(T[] a)
        Returns an array containing all of the elements in this list in the correct order;
        the runtime type of the returned array is that of the specified array.
```

You're using the first one, which is supposed to return `Object[]` and it's doing so. If you want to get correct type use the second version:

```
things.toArray(new Thing[things.length]);
```

or if you don't want to waste any more space on `new Thing[things.length]` then just change the loop to cast:

```
Thing thing = null;
for (Object o : someInstanceOfBlahBlah.getThings())
{
    thing = (Thing) o;
    // some unrelevant code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
things.toArray(new Thing[0])
```

[List.toArray javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray%28T%5B%5D%29)