# Why I cannot add ArrayList directly to Jlist?

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, jlist

i am trying to add ArrayList to Jlist, but the only way that I given to understand is that to write the code like this :

```
ArrayList<String> labels = new ArrayList<String>();
JList jlist = new JList(labels.toArray());
```

Whats confusing me is that, why i cannot just add ArrayList to Jlist directly like this :

```
ArrayList<String> labels = new ArrayList<String>();
JList jlist = new JList(labels);
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: `"Whats confusing me is that, why i cannot just add ArrayList to Jlist directly like this:"` --- Because we can't just make up code and hope that it might work. The API will tell you exactly what constructors and methods are available. The more you use it the more useful it will become.

Comment: If you're really upset about it, create a `ListModel` that uses the `List` as it's core backing data...

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3269560/363573

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The inclusion of "helper" constructors was meant to make it easier to use the `JList` with simple data structures.

The `JList` (and many Swing components) are actually meant to be used with models that supply the actual data to the view.

The original design goes way back before Swing was incorporated into the main library (prior to JDK 1.3) and just before the collections API was introduced, so it's likely that the original developers didn't have `List` available to them (hence the inclusion of `Vector`).

It's likely that no one has seen fit to update the libraries since (partially because it may have been decided that the original constructors shouldn't have been included, but I wasn't at that meeting ;))

A better/simpler solution would be to create your own model that uses the `List` as it's data source.

For example...

```
public class MyListModel<T> extends AbstractListModel<T> {

    private List<T> people;

    public MyListModel(List<T> people) {
        this.people = people;
    }

    @Override
    public int getSize() {
        return people.size();
    }

    @Override
    public T getElementAt(int index) {
        return people.get(index);
    }
}
```

Then you can simply supply it to the `JList` when ever you need to...

```
JList myList = new JList(new MyListModel<MyObject>(listOfMyObjets));
```

Comment: While both Collections and Swing debuted in Java 1.2 (in 2000), Swing was available earlier as a stand-alone library.

Answer (score 3):

`JList` has no constructor that accepts a `List`. The first example works as it uses the constructor [JList(Object[])](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html#JList%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29).

Familiarize yourself with the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html)

Answer (score 2):

Because `JList` doesn't have a constructor that accepts an `ArrayList` (or a `List`). It can only accept an array, a `ListModel`, or a `Vector`. See [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html#constructor_summary).

An `ArrayList` is not an array. You can't pass an `ArrayList` to a method that wants an array.

Answer (score 2):

It's simple. JList constructors don't expect ArrayList

```
JList()
Constructs a JList with an empty, read-only, model.
JList(E[] listData)
Constructs a JList that displays the elements in the specified array.
JList(ListModel<E> dataModel)
Constructs a JList that displays elements from the specified, non-null, model.
JList(Vector<? extends E> listData)
Constructs a JList that displays the elements in the specified Vector.
```