# Move an item from one list/arraylist to another list/arraylist

Tags: java, arrays, netbeans, awt

How to move an item from one list/arraylist to another list/arraylist?

Here's what I am required to do

- Add songs from a text field to a music library `ArrayList`.
- Select songs in the List Box and add them to the Playlist.
- Select songs in the Playlist List Box and remove them from the Playlist.
- Sort the songs in the Playlist.

I finally figured out how to add items to an arraylist and display them in a listbox.  Now I need to know how to select them and move them to another list/array using a button.

Any ideas?

Comment: Take a look at [**this**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17226489/why-i-cannot-add-arraylist-directly-to-jlist/17226629#17226629) which suggest that you need to create a `ListModel` which uses your `List` as it's data source.  The code your teacher gave is for working with `List`s from the collections API, not `JList`.  You may also want to check out [How to use lists](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html) for more details

Comment: Thanks, i found out i was supposed to use AWT lists instead of Swing lists.  Ive updated my question but i was able to get the first list box to display the array

Answer (score 2):

It will be easier for you to use `ListModel` as suggested by MadProgrammer

You can try like this

```
model = new DefaultListModel<String>();
    for(String str : playlist){
         model.addElement(str);
    }    
    listPlaylist.setModel(model);     
    listPlaylist.setSelectedIndex(0);
```

You can create two models for library and playlist and perform operations

Comment: Well I dont know hoe to make the arraylist my teacher gave me into an  area, heres the code he told me to use for it

    private ArrayList<String>  library = new ArrayList<String>();

And ass for using .setlistdata Its giving me the same error as .add and .setText

Comment: I managed to make the arraylist into an array, but now my library.add(txtSong.getText()); isnt working, and highlights .add

Comment: check a sample here it will be easier for u....http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/AnexampleofJListwithaDefaultListModel.htm