# connecting Arraylist with GUI

Tags: java, arraylist

I've created a method that returns an arraylist of object now I want to display the returned arraylist in a Jlist in swing eclipse
how can I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Create the JList with a DefaultListModel.

```
DefaultListModel listModel= new DefaultListModel();
for (int i = 0; i < arrayList().size(); i++)
{
    listModel.addElement(arrayList().get(i));
}
JList listd = new JList(listModel);
listd.setModel(listModel);
```

Plese refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3269516/java-arraylists-into-jlist) answer in stackoverflow,

Comment: I'm not adding elements I'm adding an arraylist of type Object I've tried this code but it didn't work

Comment: I changed my previous answer.Please check the solution.It may be help you

Comment: in 3rd line listModel cannot be resolved !! I can't understand the reason